# In Bash, why can we set some environment variable by PS1='something' and others need to be export SOME_VAR='something'?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

And why is an `export` needed?  Where is it exporting to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash: defining a variable with or without export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export)

Comment: I'm still wondering about "where is it exporting to." Is it being saved somewhere permanently?

Comment: If I just type the command `export` alone in Cygwin, I get a big list of env vars. 

So I exported one I needed for a program and then typed `export` again and sure enough it showed up there. 

However, it did not show up when I looked under My Computer > Advanced > Environment Variables (Win XP), and I checked both User and System. I kind of expected it to be there, so I'm a little stumped, because those env vars and others showed up in the big list. 

If it had been there, I could have clicked Delete. I wonder where it is ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exported variables are passed on to new processes invoked.

Try setting `A=1`, then invoking a new shell by entering "bash", then `echo $A` - an empty line.

Do the same, but then `export A=1`, invoke a new shell, then `echo $A` - voila!

**edit** on the technical side, and looking at your question, B=1 doesn't actually set an environment variable. To get the *real* environment of your shell (in linux), try

```
$ xargs -n 1 -0 echo < /proc/$$/environ
```

which differs from the output of `export`. And as a sidenote, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275015/ld-preload-affects-new-child-even-after-unsetenvld-preload/3275799#3275799) touches on the internals of bash and its environment handling.

Answer (score 1):

The `PS1` environment variable is pre-defined by the `bash` shell; consequently, it doesn't need to be exported, merely set.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't need to be exported, because the only one needing it is bash itself, and not it's (grand)children.

Comment: @mvds No, it doesn't need to be exported because it's already an environment variable.

Comment: 3 checks say that's not true (by default in bash 3.2.39) : 1) `export |grep PS1` 2) `xargs -n 1 -0 echo < /proc/$$/environ` and 3) `echo "main(int i,char**v,char**e){while(*e)printf(\"%s\n\",*e++);}" | gcc -x c - && ./a.out |grep PS1`. `set` however *does* show PS1. Note that all of these methods show `PATH` which I believe is a true "environment variable" (don't know your exact definition btw)