# Want the excutable run by execve() to use my preloaded library

Tags: c, linux, fork

I am executing a program say A from another by first fork-ing followed by execve(). Now the problem is I would want A to use my library that I would generaly do by using LD_PRELOAD. How do I do it within execve().

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can pass the LD_PRELOAD in envp execve's argument:

the program that gets execved, named "run":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    printf("%s\n",getenv("LD_PRELOAD"));
}
```

the program that does the execve, named "ex":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *const args[] = {"./run",NULL};
    char *const envs[] = {"LD_PRELOAD=caca",NULL};
    execve("./run",args,envs);
}
```

running it:

```
root@pinkpony:~# ./ex
ERROR: ld.so: object 'caca' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
caca
```

EDIT:
the error shown gets thrown because "caca" lib can't be preloaded for run, so it works. (I skipped the fork() part for clarity but the usage is the same)

EDIT:
doing something like:

```
LD_PRELOAD=caca ./ex
```

will not automagically preload caca lib when execve()-ing run if you're not passing it via envp execve()'s argument

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After reading the added info from the question, I'm guessing that you might have to specify a complete path, or set LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well? Since the loader **is** acknowledging the fact that the preload is ordered.

Otherwise, I can imagine there being a security restriction (allthough it would have to be tied to being run invoked from a login shell, which seems quite brittle to detect). Nonetheless, you may wish to try running as root (use `sudo -E` to keep your environment)

---

It would appear from [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275015/ld-preload-affects-new-child-even-after-unsetenvld-preload) that such behaviour is the default

[LD_PRELOAD affects new child even after unsetenv("LD_PRELOAD")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275015/ld-preload-affects-new-child-even-after-unsetenvld-preload)

Have you tested it?

Comment: the behavior doesn't apply when execve()-ing

Comment: No...enivornment of the parent does not effect the child

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use LD_PRELOAD just for program A (and not for its parent) you could load it via the shell; pass to the shell the name of the program to execute and add LD_PRELOAD to the environment.